# RAFT config question: how to Remove a node from a specific channel, but keeping it servicing other channels

Tags: nodes, hyperledger-fabric, channel

I've read [this guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/raft_configuration.html).

Removing a node from a specific channel, but keeping it servicing other channels is done by:

1. Removing its endpoint from the channel config for the channel.
2. Removing its entry (identified by its certificates) from the channel configuration.

I would like to know how to do so? Is it related to these parts in [configtx](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/configtx.html)?

1. Removing its endpoint in below list:

   ```
   "OrdererAddresses":common.OrdererAddresses,
   ```
2. Removing its entry (identified by its certificates) in MSP map

   ```
   "Orderer":&ConfigGroup{... map<string, *ConfigValue>{"MSP":msp.MSPConfig
   ```

I ran the default sample of hyperledger with 5 RAFT orderers.
I tried to use `configtxlator` to get the channel config from channel.

```
peer channel fetch config config_block.pb  -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel  --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

Why is there only one address? Am I supposed to make change to it?

```
  "OrdererAddresses": {
    "mod_policy": "/Channel/Orderer/Admins",
    "value": {
      "addresses": [
        "orderer.example.com:7050"
      ]
    },
```

Thanks in advance for useful hints to config this "Removing a node from a specific channel, but keeping it servicing other channels".

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there only one address? Am I supposed to make change to it?
>
> ```
>   "OrdererAddresses": {
>     "mod_policy": "/Channel/Orderer/Admins",
>     "value": {
>       "addresses": [
>         "orderer.example.com:7050"
>       ]
>     },
> ```

First of all this configuration section contains ordering service nodes endpoints for peer to get connected to, what you really need is the consenters configuration which resides at:

```
{
  "ConsensusType": {
    "mod_policy": "Admins",
    "value": {
      "metadata": {
        "consenters": [
          {
            "client_tls_cert": LS0tCg==
            ",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 36003,
            "server_tls_cert": LS0tCg==
            "
          },
          {
            "client_tls_cert": LS0tCg==
            ",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 36000,
            "server_tls_cert": LS0tCg==
            "
          },
          {
            "client_tls_cert": LS0tCg==
            ",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 36006,
            "server_tls_cert": LS0tCg==
            "
          }
        ],
        "options": {
          "election_tick": 10,
          "heartbeat_tick": 1,
          "max_inflight_blocks": 5,
          "snapshot_interval_size": 1024,
          "tick_interval": "500ms"
        }
      },
      "state": "STATE_NORMAL",
      "type": "etcdraft"
    }
  }
```

therefore you need to update it and remove or add consenter based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/raft_setting_how_to_do_this/31684715?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,31684715), you need to reconfigure your channel to exclude the orderer nodes from the elements `.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses` and `.channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters` array.

An example script can be found here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-test/blob/master/tools/PTE/CITest/scenarios/PTECIutils.sh#L194